# Base64 Valid Character To Encode

Tags: char, base64, encode

Which characters are encodable for base64? It is possible to create a text unencodable with base64?

Comment: unencodable text -> a text which is not represented as sequence of octets?

Answer (score 0):

[Base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) takes groups of 3 bytes (3 x 8 = 24 bits) and converts them to 4 x 6 bits (also 24 bits).

Since the conversion happens on the binary data, all data (including all characters) can be encoded.